# Does the Orchid's Soul Burn amplifies magic damage?

Tags: dota-2, dota

Does casting *magic damaging spells* on a unit under **Soul Burn** of *Orchid of Malevolence* will add up on the **amplified damage** on the end of it's duration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all damage (including spell damage) taken while under the effects of Orchid Malevolence's Soul Burn will be amplified and applied as magic damage at the end of the duration.

Source: [Play Dota Orchid Malevolence](http://www.playdota.com/items/orchid-malevolence)